# How to Pivot in SQL, grouped in 3 columns with '000s of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use the pivot function in SQL. The pivoted column has '000s of values but no more than 3 per row

The Original query shows;

| ID | Name | ThemeID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Game A | 44 |
| 11 | Game A | 791 |
| 11 | Game A | 1422 |
| 23 | Game B | 42 |
| 23 | Game B | 285 |
| 23 | Game B | 1256 |

What I need;

| ID | Name | ThemeID1 | ThemeID2 | ThemeID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Game A | 44 | 791 | 1422 |
| 23 | Game B | 42 | 285 | 1256 |

Comment: Have you already tried to craft some query about it?

Comment: You need to pivot on the value of the `ROW_NUMBER`, by the looks of it

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that uses a conditional aggregation.  We also use the window function `row_number() over()` to calculate the row and column numbers

Note: I added `Game B - 1500` to illustrate the "overflow"

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[Name] varchar(50),[ThemeID] int)  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (11,'Game A',44)
,(11,'Game A',791)
,(11,'Game A',1422)
,(23,'Game B',42)
,(23,'Game B',285)
,(23,'Game B',1256)
,(23,'Game B',1500)  -- Added to illustrate more than 3

Select ID
      ,Name
      ,ThemeID1 = max(case when CN = 1 then ThemeID end)
      ,ThemeID2 = max(case when CN = 2 then ThemeID end)
      ,ThemeID3 = max(case when CN = 0 then ThemeID end)
 From ( 
        Select * 
              ,RN = (row_number() over (partition by ID,Name order by ThemeID)-1) / 3
              ,CN = row_number() over (partition by ID,Name order by ThemeID) % 3
         From @YourTable
      ) A
 Group By ID,Name,RN
```

**Results**

```
ID  Name    ThemeID1    ThemeID2    ThemeID3
11  Game A  44          791         1422
23  Game B  42          285         1256
23  Game B  1500        NULL        NULL
```

Comment: @Ken being new to SO, when you get an answer that helps, be sure to ACCEPT it ... it indicates to other contributors that the problem has been resolved.